# Trying to setup TLS on Rsyslog server, s_client connects but gets no certs, hangs

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, rsyslog

I'm trying to set up TLS on an rsyslog server using various tutorials including rsyslog's official docs: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/tls.html.

I'm running rsyslog-8.33.1 along with the same version of rsyslog-gnutls. OS is amazon linux v2017.09 on ec2.

Since the particular syslog client I'm using does not work with self-signed certificates, I'm signing with our domain's CA. I've set up the key, cert and grabbed the CA chain (since there's intermediate certs to the root) and set up rsyslog.conf like many tutorials tell me:

```
# RsyslogGnuTLS
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/pki/tls/CA-chain.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/pki/tls/<hostname>.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/<hostname>.key
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # TLS mode only
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *
$InputTCPServerRun 6514
```

And got rsyslog to start without complaint (after some kerjigering).

This is an ec2 host with port 6514 open to the world. Now, I'm testing with openssl s_client and I can't get the certificates from the machine.

```
[me@my_host ~]$ openssl s_client -connect ec2-<ip>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:6514
CONNECTED(00000003)

(hangs)
```

... and it hangs there blankly forever until I kill the rsyslog server at which point it errors out with "no peer certificate available".

I know the rsyslog server works. It gets logs on 6514 from the syslog client when TLS is turned off on both sides.

I've tried almost every combination of variables in rsyslog.conf and I'm at my wit's end. I've also tried using the cert/key/CA bundle in /etc/pki/tls/certs that get shipped with the machine, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was using the wrong variables - the client side variables instead of server side variables, which look similar on the ends. I should have been using

```
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverPermittedPeer *
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1
```

on the server instead of

```
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1.
```

Just needed to see it with fresh eyes.